# Plain JavaScript: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html

I use:
   
    in head section of html file, to access this particular plain javascript file located in same location as my html file.
I get required output in chrome browser, whereas it shows the following error in Microsoft edge, stackblitz, jsfiddle etc.:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
GET https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/myJS.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

I have no problem / error and get the required output in google chrome browser.

```
<html>  
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
     <script src="myJS.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 style="margin: 50px">Mine Field Table</h1> 
            .. .. ..
            .. .. ..
        </div> 
    </body>
```

I expect table with smooth functionality in the output, which I do get in google chrome. But it does not seem to work elsewhere, and only html mark-up appears with no table output

Comment: The code you posted is not enough to help you with the issue (it should be working if the situation is as you describe it). That url is a bit suspect, and makes me think you're running it on an online editor. Which I doubt has the file you need on their server. Actually, even the root of that server gives a 404. So, what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I notice that there's no base href declaration in your html. I'm guessing Chrome managed to guess correctly, while other browsers didn't. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Well, if I try to load your URL `https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/myJS.js` it says 404 even in Chrome. How did you succeed to fetch a file from this URL ?